# Can't execute "system" command on Android 8 Oreo

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-8.0-oreo

In our Android Service application, we use JNI to invoke C++ code of a shared library. In this code, we invoke C "system" command to execute antoher process. This code has worked perfectly on all Android OS and now it fails on Android 8 Oreo. 
Is there any new security or other restriction the prevent to execute system commands?

Some more data:

This "c" code successfully executed from my shared library:

int error = system("ls -l /sdcard/tmp >> /sdcard/tmp/log.txt");

The file log.txt is populated as expected and the error = 0;

But this command consistently fails with unexpected error code (40704):

int error = system("/system/bin/7za t /sdcard/tmp/Camera.7z >> /sdcard/tmp/log.txt");

I can execute this command from shell ("adb shell"). 7za is a compatible Android application and it doesn't have writable and executable segments (readelf --program-headers -W libBadFlags.so | grep WE).

I tried to locate 7za in many places on my rooted Android device and with different permissions but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Android 8.0 Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#o-sec) states, that:

> **Native libraries**
>
> In apps targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26), native libraries no longer load if they contain any load segment that is both writable and executable. Some apps might stop working because of this change if they have native libraries with incorrect load segments. This is a security-hardening measure.

For more information, see [Writable and Executable Segments](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md).

> Linker changes are tied to the API level that an app targets. If there is a linker change at the targeted API level, the app cannot load the library. If you are targeting an API level lower than the API level where the linker change occurs, logcat shows a warning.

I'd guess you would need to set `android:extractNativeLibs="false"` in the `Mainfest.xml` - that's at least what the documentation states; so that's probably worth a try... and/or the native library's segments would need to be arranged differently.

This is somehow a quite theoretical question, unless having some kind of error message available, which should be thrown when enabling the native debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to build a sample code that shows the problem.

Comment: I've just added some more data to my questions

Comment: @Amiad did you drop in the `7za` binary manually? including LZMA compression as a native library (inside the app package) appears more likely to be a portable solution: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html - also consider that SE Linux labeling might prevent the execution, if not the expected context is given; `ls -laZ /system/bin` might provide a clue. you could try `semanage`  to label properly and/or `restorecon` to fix the security context (it should be the same as any other binary in there).

Comment: @Amiad in order to obatin a stacktrace of the issue, you could try `system("strace /system/bin/7za t /sdcard/tmp/Camera.7z >> /sdcard/tmp/log.txt")` ...